# Mysql db not updating to specified timezone

Tags: php, mysql, apache, amazon-ec2

I've specified the timezone in my php.ini file as East Coast time:

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = America/New_York

$ service apache2 restart
```

But yet my database datetime entries specify Western Time (3 hours behind). When I look at the timezone in MySQL console, it says SYSTEM, which I always assumed it got from whichever scripting language was running on the server. In apache2.conf, I see know way to change the timezone, so nothing there.

Anybody have any clue on how I can get my entries on the right track without having to specify the correct timezone in each and every single php file running on my shared server? If it's any consolation, I'm running an EC2 instance on the US West - Oregon region. Anything I can change in my EC2 Console Dashboard?

Comment: you can read how mysql sets timezone, here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//time-zone-support.html

Comment: @Nelson I don't think you read my question carefully before responding. From the link you provided: "The value 'SYSTEM' indicates that the time zone should be the same as the system time zone". My MySQL installation says SYSTEM when I run "mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;", but yet it fails to update it as such. Why, is the question.

Comment: John, I didn't meant to be harsh. That link shows 2 ways to tell mysql how to setup SYSTEM timezone when starting up, one passing --default-time-zone=timezone and other setting the TZ environment variable. You can also set the Timezone for the php connection, and you dont have to include that in all php files, that is bad design, you should create a db_connect() function that wraps the mysql function and it's included from any php files that wants to perform queries on db, so you just need to do your change in one place.

Comment: @Nelson I'm trying to change the timezone on the command line and in mysql:   root@ip-##:/# --default-time-zone-'America/New_York'
-bash: --default-time-zone-America/New_York: No such file or directory
root@ip-##:/# --default-time-zone-'US/Eastern'
-bash: --default-time-zone-US/Eastern: No such file or directory   mysql> SET GLOBAL time_zone = timezone;
ERROR 1298 (HY000): Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'timezone'
mysql> SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'America/New_York';
ERROR 1298 (HY000): Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'America/New_York'

Comment: what linux distro and version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

> "in MySQL console, it says SYSTEM, which I always assumed it got from
>   whichever scripting language was running on the server".

Not so, sorry to say. @Nelson is right. MySQL gets its default time zone from the mysqld server machine's default time zone setting.  The timezone setting for the scripting language has nothing to do with the case.

Is your mysqld running in your EC2 instance? If so you need to change the default time zone setting for that OS instance. You can look up how to do that.  You may find it helpful to reboot your EC2 instance after you change the default time zone.

For minimal confusion, it's a good idea to set the system time zone to UTC (also known as Z or Zulu time, formerly known as Greenwich Mean Time). That way things won't bounce around when daylight savings kicks on or off.

Comment: Not to be that guy, but @Nelson pointed me to a link I had been on before. I was looking for more clarification on this statement "The value 'SYSTEM' indicates that the...". I knew the default time zone came from the server, but I didn't know where, as per my comment: "In apache2.conf, I see know way to change the timezone, so nothing there." That's why I kindly asked him to read my question again. Now you're telling me that my assumption that MySQL timezone isn't based on that of the scripting language, leading me down the right path. I need to know how I can change the server timezone.

Comment: To find out how to change the server time zone, you can use google and ask "change default time zone setting on Red Hat Enterprise Linux" or maybe "change default time zone setting on Windows 2008 Server" or whatever is relevant.  It's a system administration task.  Also, if you're going to be running cloud server instances, it's probably a good idea read up on the relationships between web servers (apache), php scripting engines, database servers, and server instances.